# Jenkins On-prem vs Cloud(AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, vmware, cloudbees

we have Jenkins currently setup on-prem planning to migrate onto AWS, what are advantages and disadvantages running on AWS and on-prem?

Comment: One reason is that Jenkins integrates with some of AWS resources, such as codebuild, codepipeline, ec2 autoscaling. So you could use these tools without going over public internet. Other would be same as any other server on an ec2 instance, scaliability, easy of backups, etc.

Answer (score 1):

By having Jenkins in AWS you gain these benefits:

- Adjustable resourcing (changing the instance type as you desire)
- Run as pay as you go mode, if only needed during certain hours only run it then.
- Scalable worker nodes (more jobs means more scale)
- More secure integration with AWS services (Use IAM roles, VPC Endpoints to services)
- Easily replaceable

By having Jenkins on-premise you gain these benefits:

- No traversing the internet to access
- If hardwares already owned you won't be paying any extra for it.

Personally I'd recommend cloud just because of the benefits that you gain from cloud compute.